# Iterating over all fields in a PDF form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf-form

I would like to modify some properties for all fields in a PDF form in response to the user clicking a button.

Which property or method will return me the collection of fields so that I can iterate over them?

Comment: please put some code to be clear

Comment: I don't have any code, because I don't have anywhere to start from in the absence of a collection to iterate over.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there is a collection of fields I still haven't found it. There is a way to iterate over all the fields though.

The `numFields` property of the doc object gives the number of fields,
`getNthFieldName(index)` returns the name of the field with that index and getField(*fieldName*) returns the field of that name.

```
for (var fieldNumber = 0; fieldNumber < numFields; fieldNumber ++)
{
  getField(getNthFieldName(fieldNumber)).value = 'Scripty Was Here';
}
```